# How to jump from the first word to fifth word in a sentence of ten words in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

for eg:

(file.py)

print(["a","b","C","d","E","f","g","8"])

i want to change: (Without using the mouse of course)

"C" to "c","E" to "e" and "8" to "h"

I do know about the "Ctrl + (Arrow Keys)" shortcut but that only jumps word by word.

What I mean is, jumping words using some sort of indexing with numbers using keyboard shortcuts.....

Comment: Unusual request. Wouldn't it take you longer to actually count how many words you were going to need to skip in the general case?

Comment: yeah but if it is separated by a space or it is possible to count or something, can we do it ?

Comment: Not aware of any intrinsic VS Code feature here, probably because no-one has ever asked for it. Perhaps you could find a macro recorder extension and record N ctrl+right-arrows and bind it to some custom key.

Comment: hmmm ok thnx anyways. I thought VS Code had some feature related to it or something...
kk thnx Jarmod. :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't exactly the scenario I designed this extension for: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) but it works pretty well in your case.

With this keybinding (in keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",                  // whatever keybinding you like
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "([A-Z0-8])",
    "replace": "${1:/downcase}",
    "isRegex": true,
    "restrictFind": "nextSelect",
    "matchCase": true
  }
}
```

[image: jump caps demo]

Obviously, it can't know what you want to do with the `8` but it will stop there and select it so you could change it easily and continue on to the next capitalized letter.

There is no built-in indexing way to do what you want, you'll need an extension of some sort.

You could also do a find/replace with

find: `([A-Z0-9])`
replace: `\L$1`

with matchCase and regex options enabled and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> would go through them one by one and downcase them and stop on the `8` for you.

Comment: what about going back i mean reversing it ?

Comment: alt + shift + y  "previousMoveCursor" function or something

Comment: Moving to a previous match isn't currently supported in the extension.  Would you like to see it implemented?

Comment: yeah sure why not

Comment: it would just make it even better

Comment: but you can take your time its fine

Comment: i just had a thought about it like trying to avoid using the mouse as much as possible. Anyway thnx for all your help.